# Design - convention in C# Date format Specifier

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a question behinf specifying format of Date in methods like ParseExact, TryParseExact etc in C#.
    `yy-year` `dd-date` `MM-month` `mm-minutes` `ss-seconds` etc

It is pretty obvious to just look into documents for understanding the formats but just curious if there is any design ideals behind naming them that way for what stands for what. I would have preferred that dates are specified using CAPS and time in lower case. 
   Just wanted to know, suppose you are in future developing .Net 10.0 :)

Comment: There's really no way to answer this question (unless you happen to be on the original design team, I suppose)

Comment: Currently, "H" corresponds to the 24-hour format, while "h" corresponds to the 12-hour format. If dates were specified with caps instead, then how could we differentiate between 24/12 hours and still be just as readable?

Comment: Agreed. But I am just trying reason for such decisions, just like you mentioned or as Reed said no body knows or just followed from old conventions. For example 24/14 hr format might have been included as a Culture Variant too.

Answer (score 1):

I think, as with all such things, it's probably a leftover convention from the days of old.

They probably started with hh:mm and thought "wait a minute, we have another m!"

I agree the decision could have been made to just caps all the date parts, but maybe they decided they didn't want to use unnecessary caps if at all possible.